# Eilenberg-Maclane space, when can $K(\pi, 1)$ be constructed as a compact manifold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511440/construct-a-connected-cw-complex-k-pi-1-such-that-pi-1k-pi-1-pi).

> Let $\pi$ be any group. Construct a connected CW complex $K(\pi, 1)$ such that $\pi_1(K(\pi, 1)) = \pi$ and $\pi_q(K(\pi, 1)) = 0$ for $q \neq 1$.

It is rarely the case that $K(\pi, 1)$ can be constructed as a compact manifold. What is a necessary condition on $\pi$ for this to happen?

Comment: For one thing, $\pi$ has to have finite cohomological dimension. (This implies, as @GrumpyParsnip mentioned below, by standard machinery that $\pi$ is torsion-free. There are also some other properties you get for free; having finite cohomological dimension is a nontrivial restriction on a group.) Also, $\pi$ has to be finitely presented.

Comment: One very restrictive condition is that $\pi$ needs to be torsion free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a group of closely related necessary conditions on the homology and cohomology of $\pi$, in order for there to be a compact **oriented** $n$-dimensional manifold $K(\pi,1)$. Usually one fixes a choice of coefficient ring $R$, commutative and with unit element $1$. These conditions hold for any choice of $R$. (One can drop the "oriented" property but things get more complicated to state).

The simplest is that for any ring $R$ the groups $H^i(\pi;R)$ equal zero in dimensions $i>n$ and $R$ in dimension $i=n$.

Another one is that the *twisted* cohomology groups $H^i(\pi ; R \pi)$ (using the natural action of $\pi$ on $R\pi$) are zero in dimensions $i \ne n$ and $R$ in dimension $i=n$ (this one does not need the oriented condition).

The most subtle and important necessary condition is that $H_*(\pi;R)$ and $H^*(\pi;R)$, with cup and cap product structures, satisfy Poincare duality, meaning that $H^n(\pi;R)=R$ and is generated by an element $\xi$ having the property that the cap product with $\xi$ defines an isomorphism $H_i(\pi;R) \leftrightarrow H^{n-i}(\pi;R)$ for all $0 \le i \le n$. One says in this case that $\pi$ is a "Poincare duality group". In dimension 2 this condition is also known to be sufficient; in dimension 3 sufficiency is a major open question; in higher dimensions I am not an expert but I believe there are counterexamples to sufficiency.

Comment: Do you know where I might be able to find a c/e?

Comment: @MikeMiller: I would start with the works of Mike Davis.

Comment: Actually, there are no known higher-dimensional counterexamples once you assume that $\pi$ is finitely presented, the one by Mike Davis is of $\pi$ which is not finitely presented. The problem itself is known as "Wall Conjecture" and it is a major open problem in higher dimensional topology.  The main recent progress is due to Bartels, Lueck and Weinberger, who proved that $\pi$ is a manifold group if $\pi$ is hyperbolic with spherical boundary and of dimension $n\ge 6$.

Answer (score 5):

$\pi$ has to be torsions free:

Let $M$ be a compact aspherical manifold and $C$ a finite cyclic subgroup of its fundamental group. As $M$ is aspherical, its universal covering $\tilde{M}$ is contractible, so the quotient $\tilde{M}/C$ provides a finite dimensional model for the classifying space $BC$ of $C$. In particular, $C$ has nonzero homology groups only in finitely many degrees. This implies that $C$ is trivial.

Comment: Of course, all we've done is obstruct a finite complex. Wall has an equivalent condition on $\pi$ for $K(\pi,1)$ to enjoy the structure of a finite complex; then making it a manifold is harder yet, as in Lee Mosher's answer.

Answer (score -3):

If $\pi$ acts freely and properly on $R^n$ and the quotient is compact. Example $\pi=Z^n$ $K(Z^n,1)$ is the n-dimensional torus.

Comment: That's sufficient, but I don't see why it would be necessary.